# Figure in 2 columns

Tags: pdftex, multicol

So I am basic in latex and I have a document with 2 columns with pictures but my pictures are either moved to the next page and like in a single column or they are moved to the end of the document depending on changes I make to the code.

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{Untitled201-img001.jpg}
\end{figure*}
```

I have tried [ht] [h] [b] all of these things, but none of them is correcting it and I have searched a lot but just can't figure out. I am using multicol package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `multicol` manual mentions: "Stared  floats,  e.g., figure*,  denote  page  wide  floats  that  are handled  in  a  similar  fashion  as normal  floats  outside  the multicols environment.  However, they will  never  show  up  on  the  page where  they  are  encountered.   In other  words,  one  can  influence their  placement  by  specifying  a combination  of t, b,  and/or p in  their  optional  argument,  but h doesn’t  work  because  the  first possible  place  is  the  top  of  the next page. ", so the `figure*` moving to the next page is the expeced behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. Use this package.

`\usepackage{float}`

```
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```